# Can I use service account under reseller domain to create/manage users under resold domains?

Tags: google-reseller-api

As a Reseller, is it possible for me to leverage Service Account to call Reseller API and Directory API to create new domains and manage user accounts under them without requiring user interaction/login/consent?

The End-to-End tutorial for Reseller API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/codelab/end-to-end) suggests it is possible. I could create a service account under my Reseller domain. Using this service account, I can impersonate a super user admin under my Reseller domain and can achieve the above.

On the other hand, when I read through the article on Authorizing Requests (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/authorizing), it mentioned that "All requests to the Google Apps Reseller API must be authorized by an authenticated user", which seems to suggests that some form of consent is required. Further, it doesn't mention that service account is supported.

I tried to search for similar topics in the forum and I am seeing somewhat conflicting responses. The answers range from "yes, this works" to "service account not supported with Reseller API" or "API access must be manually enabled in each resold domain".

Thanks!

Comment: You can use service account with Reseller API. You should do domain wide delegation so that your service account can access data on behalf of users in domain. But make sure you impersonate google apps user who can make API calls. check this link for more information on Service account https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, I just need to impersonate a Super User admin my reseller tenant in order to manage users in my resold (customers) domain, right? I should not have to impersonate Super User Admin in my resold (customers) domain.

Comment: Did you resolve your question? I am currently having the same question as I am getting `Error 403: Access Not Configured. Admin Directory API has not been used in project` when using my reseller service account.